# jQuery core with mobile safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad, safari, cors

I've recently been working on getting CORS working on a few web applications I've built but have a mysterious problem with it comes to mobile safari on our corporate iPads.

A break down of the environment, I have a front end server that hosts the web pages.  I then have 2 different back end servers, Sharepoint 2013 and CRM 2011.  Both of which have REST services that I'm trying to access from the applications published on the front end server.

On the two back end servers, in IIS I've set the response headers to :

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: frontEndServerServername
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Origin

And on my $.ajax calls I've added

xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }.

So a simple query now looks like :

```
function getRequestDigestTEST() {
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
url: 'http://sharepoint/_api/contextinfo',
method: "POST",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
success: function(results) {
requestDigest = results.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
},
error: function (error) {
alert(error.status);
}
});
}
```

This all works great in any desktop browser, my problem however is with mobile safari.  On an iPad I get 401 unauthorized returned.  When I enable tracing on IIS, the back end servers see the authentication handed off from mobile safari as anonymous.  From a desktop browser, I see NTLM with the proper username.

I've also tried adding the username/password properties to the ajax call, but even those don't seem to get passed to the web service, as the tracing still reports anonymous authentication type.

I've hunted around and can't seem to find anything that can get the iPad talking to the back end resources.

Answer (score 0):

For Sharepoint I was able to get it working with setting 2 settings on the ajax call, but CRM I had to build my own web service that acts like a proxy for REST calls.

Unless you have anonymous setup on Sharepoint (which you most likely don't or want to), the ajax call does a pre-call.  In order to authenticate in the pre-call, we need to set the header info in the ajax call to a function.

```
authPreCall = function(req) { req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", sessionStorage.getItem("LoginToken")); };
```

In all of my apps I now check if the end user is on an iOS device, if so, I forward them to a long screen where I generate a login token based on their entered credentials.  When they then need to access a web service, I retrieve the session token and pass it onto the service.

The other ajax setting needed is the "xhrfields".

```
authFields = { withCredentials:true };
```

I then pass the authFields variable into the xhrfields property on the ajax call.

In my initial post lists required IIS properties that are also needed to be entered for the Sharepoint site you want to access.

Again, CRM is a different animal as these settings don't work, and I had to build a .NET web service that would authenticate to CRM and do a REST query from there.  So from javascript, I create a payload object that contains the REST query I need done, and the web service then conducts it and hands back the results to the interface.

Hope this helps...